# Ability to send mail from alias address?

Tags: gmail

I have a mail server with Postifx (and dovecot) setup, on which there is an alias address (say alias@example.com) which forwards mail to my main email (myname@gmail.com). This works fine, and all mail I send to alias@example.com gets sent to myname@gmail.com

However, when I reply to an email sent to alias@example.com (using the gmail web interface), to the recipient, it looks like the mail came from myname@gmail.com (or more specifically, the user of myname@gmail.com, eg. Joe Bloggs).

Is there a way to make the email look like it came from alias@example.com, or even just a custom name (such as Alias) rather than coming from *Joe Bloggs < myname@gmail.com >*?

Answer (score 2):

In the **Accounts and Import** tab of GMail settings, you can add your *myname@gmail.com* address as another email address that you own.
You can then configure Gmail to let you send messages with this email address listed as the sender instead of your GMail address. You can choose which address to use when composing a new message by click the *From* link.

For full details, see the GMail help article, [Send mail from a different address or alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en-GB).

The following answers to questions on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=mail%20account) are also relevant:

- [What does Treat as an alias do in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25493/what-does-treat-as-an-alias-do-in-gmail/25531#25531)
- [How do I get rid of “On Behalf Of” from my sent Gmail messages?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/196/how-do-i-get-rid-of-on-behalf-of-from-my-sent-gmail-messages/215#215)

Comment: Thanks for this. Do other email providers (outlook, icloud, etc.) support something similar to this?

Comment: How can I have an aliased user authenticating with the SMTP server?

Comment: @user2370460 I answered your question (as you worded it) yesterday after spending more a lot more time than I intended to. Asking about authenticating GMail with SMTP servers is shifting the goalposts (though I actually came back to my answer later yesterday afternoon and edited it to include a SE link which shows how).